# Vital statistics of the United States (early 20th century)

Tags: us-census, historical

The US census bureau published annual volumes in its series "Vital Statistics of the United States" between 1890 and 1930.

Each report is available as a pdf here:
https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/products/vsus/vsus_1890_1938.htm

Has anyone digitized these records?

Comment: PDF is a digital format, I'm guessing you mean: "has anyone put these into a machine-readable format"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The National Historical Geographic Information System has digitized [Vital Statistics from 1915 through 1970](https://www.nhgis.org/user-resources/datasets-overview#dsg75).